# Contour integration, cos(z)sin(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Gamma}\cos(z)\sin(z)dz,~\Gamma:\gamma(t):=\pi t+(1-t)i,~0\leq t\leq 1.
\end{equation*}

I think I should do it using this
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int^b_a f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt
\end{equation*}

but when I sub in gamma the integral seems very difficult? Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: so, is the answer $sin^2(1)$/$2$?

Comment: Not quite, check the start and end points of $\gamma$ again.

Comment: $-sin^2(i)$/$2$?

Comment: Or, more complete, $\frac{\sin^2 \pi}{2} - \frac{\sin^2 i}{2}$. Which evaluates to $\frac{\sinh^2 1}{2}$, by the way.

Comment: ah,thank you, that was much easier than what I was originally trying to do :)